# How to put search bar in navigation bar programmatically? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, swift4

I'm using this library and my view looks like this pic:

[image: view with searchbar]

I added a search bar in homeViewController.

**HomeViewController**

```
func createSearchBar(){
        searchbar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchbar.placeholder = "searchbartext".localized()
        searchbar.delegate = self
        self.navigationItem.titleView = searchbar
    }
```

***My question is***:  How can I use this searchbar (in HomeViewController) in child view controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an SearchController and set it up to show the results in another TableViewController:

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    var controladorDeBusca: UISearchController!

    var resultsTableViewController: ResultsTableViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        resultsTableViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "resultsTableViewController") as? ResultsTableViewController

        configurarControladorDeBusca()
    }

    func configurarControladorDeBusca() {

        controladorDeBusca = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsTableViewController)
        controladorDeBusca.delegate = self
        controladorDeBusca.searchResultsUpdater = resultsTableViewController
        controladorDeBusca.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        definesPresentationContext = true

        controladorDeBusca.loadViewIfNeeded()

        //Configura a barra do Controlador de busca
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.delegate = resultsTableViewController
        controladorDeBusca.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.placeholder = "Search place"
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.barTintColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
        controladorDeBusca.searchBar.tintColor = self.view.tintColor

        //Adiciona a barra do Controlador de Busca a barra do navegador
        navigationItem.titleView = controladorDeBusca.searchBar
    }
}
```

ResultsTableViewController

```
import UIKit

class ResultsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var array = ["Brazil", "Bolivia", "United States", "Canada", "England", "Germany", "France", "Portugal"]

    var arrayFilter = [String]()

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return arrayFilter.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = arrayFilter[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }


    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {


    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        arrayFilter.removeAll()

        if let text = searchBar.text {
            for string in array {
                if string.contains(text) {
                    arrayFilter.append(string)
                }
            }
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        arrayFilter.removeAll()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

        arrayFilter.removeAll()
        tableView.reloadData()

        return true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: No problem. If it solved your issue, please mark it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: Please translate your function names and comments to English when posting to StackOverflow.

Comment: hey man! when i click a cell didselectrow , perforsegue don't work. why ?@GuiDupas

Comment: You must implement the `didSelectRow` method

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why the title of this question is "How to put search bar in navigation bar programmatically? - Swift", but the solution that was offered is using an Xcode storyboard interface template. Either the user who asked the question did not understand the difference and accepted the answer or the person who offered the solution answered it not realizing the solution was instantiating using a storyboard. At any rate this is misleading to me and it should be renamed.