# UISearchResultsUpdating not conforming to extension class in view controller

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to get something like instagrams explore page, example [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4BbL.jpg) (image is too large for adding it onto the post). I have an explore viewController with a search bar at the top and a collection view for the content underneath the search bar, whenever the user clicks the search bar it'll go to my search table view controller class which gives them the results of users that match their query and vice versa.

Here's my normal search view controller (the main one where it shows the content):

```
import UIKit

class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    guard let SearchResultsViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultsViewController") as? SearchTableViewController else { return}

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: SearchResultsViewController)

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = SearchTableViewController // ERROR HERE

    view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
}
```

and here's my search table view controller:

```
class SearchTableViewController: UIViewController {

let languages = ["Mandarin Chinese", "English", "Hindustani", "Spanish", "Arabic", "Malay", "Russian", "Bengali", "Portuguese", "French", "Hausa", "Punjabi", "German", "Japanese", "Persian", "Swahili", "Telugu", "Javanese", "Wu Chinese", "Korean"]
var searchResults: [String] = []

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
}

}

extension SearchTableViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
    searchResults = languages.filter { $0.contains(searchText) }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}

extension SearchTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return searchResults.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath)

    let language = searchResults[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = language
    return cell
}
}
```

At the moment I'm stuck on calling the `searchResultsUpdating` class. With an error of `Cannot assign value of type 'SearchTableViewController.Type' to type 'UISearchResultsUpdating?'`. My `SearchTableViewController` has the `UISearchResultsUpdating` delegate in the extension of the class, I don't know where I've gone wrong? I'm trying to achieve something like [Pete's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48687827/12647189)  with this design:

[image]

Obviously without the tab navigation bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont you need an instance of `SearchTableViewController`?

You are trying to assign class type instead of an instance of it here:

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = SearchTableViewController
```

You need to either initalize SearchTableViewcontroller or have a reference to an instance of it to set as `searchResultsUpdater`

Comment: yeh...that's a good point. Which made me realise I was referencing the wrong instance, I needed to reference the `guard let SearchResultsViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchResultsViewController") as? SearchTableViewController else { return}` variable I made, not the actual storyboard itself, hahah. I'll mark it as the answer as it technically is. Thanks!

Comment: yeah sometimes it is easy to overlook and dive deeper to find a solution :D

Comment: just need a fresh pair of eyes to realise dumb mistakes